# htmlagility - GetElementbyId error

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

i have a list in c#. i used the list to store the ID. my task is to retrieve the href of the ID.

```
<item href="Text/Cover.xhtml" id="Cov" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/Back.xhtml" id="Back" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
```

above is the html code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (string value in list)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(value);
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    document2.Load(@"C:\try.html");

                    string tag = document2.GetElementbyId(value).Name;
                    string href = document2.GetElementbyId(value).GetAttributeValue("href", "");
                    MessageBox.Show(href);
                }
```

the code above doesn't work.

but the code below works perfectly when i type the ID. why does it works? my code above simply pass the value of the list. and the first value of the list is "cov". so whats the difference? thank you so much. im really confused right now. whats the problem

```
string tag = document2.GetElementbyId("cov").Name;
                        string href = document2.GetElementbyId("cov").GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Comment: what was the error message exactly?

Comment: Well maybe you forgot some code, but in your current snippet your list is always empty. Don't you wanted to add a line like `list.add("cov")` ?

Comment: @har07 it says {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @bviale i have items on the list sir( i have other code to populate the list. but i didn't add it to the snippet to avoid confusion. i even added MessageBox.Show(value); to check if the value has a value

Answer (score 0):

i already found the problem

the items on the list contains white space. so i need trim() in order to make it work

```
string tag = document2.GetElementbyId(value.Trim()).Name;
                    string href = document2.GetElementbyId(value.Trim()).GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```